Laravel: convert the value of metadata into a separate boolean
I am making a voicelog conversation controller for some requests made for the front end to display i am allowing some data and some data needs to be excluded
  public function index(): JsonResponse
    {
        $allowedMetadata = [
            'queue_display_name',
            'campaign_display_name',
            'finished',
            'transfer_destination',
            'direction',
            'record_expires',
            'cur_call_uid',
            'call_recording', //keep unexposed
            'has_recording // if call recording is true make this true, otherwise false
        ];

        request()->validate([
            'from'  => 'date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z',
            'until' => 'date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z',
        ]);

        $orderBy = request()->has('order_by') ? request('order_by') : "answered_at";
        $direction = request()->has('order_by') && request('direction') === "asc" ? "asc" : "desc";

//some request ordering code...

//some request query parsing code...

 
        $conversations = $query->paginate();
        foreach ($conversations as &$conversation) {
            foreach ($conversation->metadata as $key => $value) {
                if (!in_array($key, $allowedMetadata)) {
                    $conversation->metadata->forget($key);
                }
            }
        }
        return response()->json($conversations);
    }

in this case 'call_recording' is a url string which i want to keep unexposed. i want to make that value a boolean called 'has_recording'  so that i can display a button in the front end if it is true, and not display if has_recording is false
how do i add an extra value to the api that has this booolean 'has_recording', while unexposing the call_recording url string?
i wanna iterate through all conversations and add a default value 'has_recording' like this in the store() function, but i want to add this value to the metadata
$reqHasCallRecording = false;
        foreach ($request->metadata as $metadataData) {
            if ($metadataData['key'] == 'call_recording') {
                $reqHasCallRecording = true;
                break;
            }
        }

i found out you can to this with Eloquent but not sure how to go about it?
Any help is appreciated.

And what have you tried so far?

i solved my problem by iterating through every conversation and setting a new metadata property ' has recording' to true whenever there is a cal recording available
    foreach ($conversations as &$conversation) {
        foreach ($conversation->metadata as $key => $value) {

            if ($key == 'call_recording') {
                $conversation->metadata['has_recording'] = isset($conversation->metadata['call_recording']);
            }
            if (!in_array($key, $allowedMetadata)) {
                $conversation->metadata->forget($key);
            }
        }
    }

